# The IF statement parameter dimensional x in BASH script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, parameter

I have found this in an old script but can't tell what is the use of the "**x**" infront of the `${VARIABLE}`  and infront of the value "on**x**" being compared

```
VARIABLE="${VARIABLE:-"on"}"
if [ "${VARIABLE}x" != "onx" ]
```

Are there any effects if the **`x`** is removed?

Comment: It's not needed with proper quoting (which you have) and a vaguely modern shell (which you probably also have), so go ahead and remove it. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174119/why-do-shell-script-comparisons-often-use-xvar-xyes).

Comment: In any modern shell, or at least in `bash`, there will be no difference to the outcome of the test if `x` is removed. See the dupe questions.

Comment: It's also not needed because of the preceding line that sets `VARIABLE` to a value if it's either unset or empty. Since now `VARIABLE` cannot be empty the `x` guard isn't required